# Prove $c\vec{v}+d\vec{w}$ with $0 ≤ c,d ≤ 1$ fill the parallelogram with sides $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> For vectors  $\vec{v},\vec{w}\in\mathbb{R}^2$, prove that the combinations $c\vec{v}+d\vec{w}$ with $0 ≤ c ≤ 1$ and $0 ≤ d ≤ 1$ fill the parallelogram with sides $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$

If I take a simple examples like $\vec{v}=(1,0)$ and $\vec{w}=(0,1)$
$$
c\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0
\end{bmatrix}+d\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
c\\d
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
x\in[0,1]\\y\in[0,1]
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But how do I prove it mathematically for the general case ?

This is stated by @Jack D'Aurizio in the post [Decide if a point is inside parallelogram](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642918/decide-if-a-point-is-inside-parallelogram), but no proof is given.

**My Attempt**

[image: pic]
$$
\vec{r}=c\vec{v}+d\vec{w}\\
c,d\in[0,1]\implies c+d\in[0,2]\\
\text{when }c+d\in[0,1]\implies c\leq 1-d\\
\vec{r}\leq (1-d)\vec{v}+d\vec{w}=\vec{v}+d(\vec{w}-\vec{v}) \\
\implies\vec{r} \text{ fills the triangle }\Delta OAB\\
$$
When $c+d\in[1,2]$ how do I prove that $\vec{r}$ span the other half of the parallelogram ?

Comment: How to you define the *filled parallelogram*?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I think that is where the confusion lies, could you please put some insights into it ?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The boundary lines are $\vec{r}=\vec{u}+t\vec{v}$ and $\vec{r}=\vec{v}+n\vec{u}$, right ? Thats the only thing I am able to define.

Comment: Note $c+d\in[1,2]$ doesn't imply $c,d\in[0,1]$

Comment: I think what mathcounterexamples is getting at is that this equation can be *the definition* of the parallelogram (and its interior).  But if you question that then there must be some other definition you are using, and providing that definition is more-or-less essential to deriving the equation form from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

By the figure above, $$\vec u = \vec v+ \alpha \vec w$$ with $\alpha \in [0,1]$. See that the vector $\vec u$ takes the "border" of the parallelogram. Furthermore, if we take $\beta \vec u$ (green vector) with $\beta \in [0,1]$ we get interior points of the parallelogram.

In this case, the vector $$\beta \vec u = \beta \vec v + \beta \alpha \vec w$$ when we vary $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the vector $\beta \vec u$ takes all interior points of the upper triangle shaped by $\vec v$ and $\alpha \vec w$. You just need to make the necessary changes to get the lower triangle.

Can you finish?

Comment: you are taking some vector $\vec{u}$ such that $\vec{w}=\vec{u}+\alpha\vec{v}$, after that I don't understand.

Comment: @ss1729: I updated the answer. Please, see if it satisfies you.

Comment: @ss1729, be carefull, there is no inequality for vectors.

Comment: A general vector inside $\sqsubset \! \sqsupset  OADB$ is $\vec{r}=a\vec{v}+b(\vec{v}+\vec{w})$ or $\vec{r}=\alpha\vec{w}+\beta(\vec{v}+\vec{w})$ with $a+b,\alpha+\beta\in[0,1]$ and $a,b,\alpha,\beta\in[0,1]$. $\vec{r}=(a+b)\vec{v}+b\vec{w}=c\vec{v}+d\vec{w}$ or $\vec{r}=\beta\vec{v}+(\alpha+\beta)\vec{w}=c\vec{v}+d\vec{w}$ with $c,d\in[0,1]$, is it right ?

Comment: @ss1729: That is right!

Answer (score 0):

To solve by triangles, rotate by $180^\circ$ about either $\frac{\vec v+\vec w}{2}$ or the origin (i.e. consider the parallelogram $(-\vec v, -\vec w)$), and the transforms $c\to 1-c, d\to 1-d$.

$\vec r = (\vec v+\vec w) - c\vec v - d\vec w = (1-c)\vec v+(1-d)\vec w$

To continue your method, try:

$$
\vec{r}=c\vec{v}+d\vec{w}\\
c,d\in[0,1]\implies c+d\in[0,2]\\
\text{when }c+d\in[1,2]\implies 1-d\leq c\leq 1\leq 2-d\\
(1-d)\vec{v}+d\vec{w}\leq\vec{r}\leq \vec{v}+d\vec{w}\\
\text{when }c+d\in[1,2]\implies 1-c\leq d\leq 1\leq 2-c\\
c\vec{v}+(1-c)\vec{w}\leq\vec{r}\leq c\vec{v}+\vec{w}\\
\implies\vec{r} \text{ fills the triangle }\triangle ABD\\
$$

I think you need to add lower bounds to your original argument for completeness.

Comment: how come $c\vec u+d\vec v = c(u_1+v_1)\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}+d(u_2+v_2)\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: $c\vec u+d\vec v =c\bigg\{u_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}+u_2\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\bigg\}+d\bigg\{v_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}+v_2\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\bigg\}\neq c(u_1+v_1)\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}+d(u_2+v_2)\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, right ?